Is the CFB mode of Encryption related-key secure
I am going through the paper https://www.iacr.org/archive/fse2013/84240283/84240283.pdf where the related key security of CBC mode of encryption is well analyzed. I am concerned about whether the CFB mode of encryption is related-key secure or not.

That paper actually doesn't discuss CBC mode; rather, it discusses "Encrypted CBC mode"; see https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2008/49650197/49650197.pdf for more details...

Thanks! but this paper does not mention anything about related-key security
